# Sum consecutive values of the same sign

Tags: mysql

A very newbie mysql question.  I have a mysql table that looks like the below, where the output column is what I am looking to produce

Test_table

```
Record_ID  Day  price_change  Output
=======================================
1          1     null          null
2          1     3             3
3          1    -1             null
4          1     0            -1
5          1     1             1
6          1    -1             null
7          1     0             null
8          1     0            -1
9          1     1             1
10         2     null          null
11         2     1             null
```

What I am looking to do is get the running total down the price_change column of records and output that total every time there is a change of sign in the values, the day changes, or the next value is null.

The record_id may not always be consecutive so it could go 10, 15, 16, 19, 20 etc.

I was trying to do it something like the below (which I does not deal with the day change), but its not behaving as I expected and I cant reset the variable after its output.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I should be approaching this please?

```
set @var := 0;
SELECT 
  rid,
  pcng,
        CASE 
       when pcng > 0 and next_price_change > 0 then @var := @var + pcng /* output null */
        when pcng < 0 and next_price_change < 0 then @var := @var + pcng /* output null */
        when pcng * next_price_change < 0 or next_price_change is null then @var + pcng
        /* how to reset the @var ??? */
      END AS output_sum
FROM (
    SELECT
        Record_ID as rid,
        Price_CHANGE as pcng,
    /* Subselect next number from next Record_ID which may not be in sequence */
    (SELECT Price_change FROM test_table WHERE Record_ID > rid ORDER BY Record_ID ASC LIMIT 1) AS next_price_change
    FROM test_table
) pcalc
```

Comment: I've never seen a good running total in SQL. Its almost always easier to do running totals on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable assignments are evaluated left-to-right in mysql, so having something like

```
mysql> set @foo=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

will give you this, dynamically updating the variable throughout the field list:

```
mysql> select @foo as first, @foo:=@foo+1 as second, @foo:=@foo+10 as third;
+-------+--------+-------+
| first | second | third |
+-------+--------+-------+
|     1 |      2 |    12 |
+-------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note now the variable started as the original 1, then was updated to the new values. Then if you re-run the same query:

```
mysql> select @foo as first, @foo:=@foo+1 as second, @foo:=@foo+10 as third;
+-------+--------+-------+
| first | second | third |
+-------+--------+-------+
|    12 |     13 |    23 |
+-------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

you start out with the **LAST** assigned value from the previous query, and update it throughout again.

So basically, just do all your in-query calculations, then as the **LAST** field in the `SELECT`, you update the variable with its new value. e.g

```
SET @prev = null;
SELECT this + @prev, that - @prev, whatever * @prev, @prev := new_value
```